# Set Theory/Cycles

Tags: finite-groups

Is there anyway/notation of taking a finite set lets say A={1,4,8,2} and turning it into cycle form where order matters for example?

[image]

Comment: But as sets, $\{1,4,8,2\}=\{1,2,4,8\}$!

Comment: I know, that's what makes it so hard! I'm trying to identify particular elements from the set though. I am wanting some kind of notation where I could transfer a set into a function where order matters.

Comment: You can speak of sequences or linearly ordered sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write the pairing explicitly:
$$
\{
\{1,1\}, \{2,4\}, \{3,8\}, \{4,2\}
\}
$$